# Converting Object received using SOAP from (C# .net) web service to a String array in Android

Tags: java, android, web-services, object, ksoap2

I am trying to send string array from web service to android application using kSOAP2.
Using kSOAP2, I receive an response in Object format at android end. Now i want to convert this object in String Array format so that i can pass this array directly to GridView.

My Web Service Method is as follows:

```
[WebMethod]
public string[] getit(string status)
{
   string[] result;
   if (status == "blue")
      result = new string[] { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four" };
   else
      result = new string[] { "five", "six", "Seven", "Eight" };
   return result;
}
```

My Android Code is as follows:

```
public void call(String status)
{
   try {    
       SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

       request.addProperty("status",status.toString());

       SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
       envelope.dotNet=true;
       envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

       HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
       androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

       Object result = (Object)envelope.getResponse();

       array1=(String []) result;   //This statement does not work
   } 
}
```

In android code array1 is globally declared string array. String array1[];
I want to convert Object result to be converted into array1 String array.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first print the "result" object using result.toString().... and see what it returns and after that it will not directly convert into the string[] first it should convert into the Object[] array... and one by one it will convert into the string[] array... so your code should be like....

Object[] objArr=(Object[])result;

String[] strArr=new String[objArr.length];

for(int i=0;i<=objArr.length;i++)

{

```
  strArr[i]=objArr[i].toString();
```

}

Thats how u can do it....

Comment: not exactly. With kSOAP2 you get SoapObjects, which contain attributes and properties. The rest is easy to handle.

Comment: @mihail Thanks for the input, can you please explain me or refer to a simple straight forward example for fetching the data in string array.

Answer (score 1):

right now I can't think of a good example. You should examine the object that is returned. But I guess that it is a SoapObject with properties inside

```
SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
```

then I guess if you call

```
String s = (String)result.getProperty(0);
```

you will get the first element of the returned array.

And ofcource, you should do the necessery error handling.